# Get and validate all elements (jquery repeater)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on a project that uses jquery repeater. I need to loop through the inputs elements to make my validations. So, here is an example of an input of my form:

```
<input name="group-fundos[0][fundo-nome]" placeholder="Nome do Fundo" type="text">
```

Ans you can see, its like an array. So I need to get all these elements via jquery. How do I do that?

Edit: One other detail. Im using multi-step form. So for each step, I need to loop through its own inputs. The inputs types can be varied: option selects, textfields, textareas, etc..

Comment: $("input[type='text']") get all, and then validate each. Or get by form fields, search any

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón the problem with your solution is that it will get all the text fields on the form. Since I have I multi-step-form, it wont work properly. Is there any other way?

Comment: create validation plugin , or use one https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón isnt there a way for loop through the groups? That would be easier I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to retrieve all values by using jQuery [serializeArray] method. For example.

```
// assuming that your input fields are inside a certain form
var oFormData = $('#multi-step-form').serializeArray();

 for (var iIndex in oFormData) {
     console.log(oFormData[iIndex].value);
 }
```

Just make sure all your [input fields] have the [name] attributes as well.
Hope this helps for your case

Comment: Thanks @eeya, your solution put me on the right track!

Comment: No problem. Glad we could help. =)

Answer (score 0):

if you are certain values begin at 0 and end at length, you could try something like:

```
var i = 0;
while($("input[name='group-fundos["+i+"][fundo-nome]']").length) {
    //validate here or build a js array for later
}
```

**Edit**

Using [attribute *contains* selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) you could get elements **like** the one provided.

`$("input[name*='group-fundos["+i+"]")` would get all elements with name beginning in "group-fundos[ i ]". (Notice the *=).

Comment: the problem is that the name of the fields wont be only something like group-fundos[0][fundo-nome]'], group-fundos[1][fundo-nome]'], etc.. 

I will have other names too, like: group-fundos[0][fundo-valor]'], group-fundos[1][fundo-valor]'], etc..